# Ansible: Converting 'AnsibleUnsafeText' to 'int' returns zero

Tags: python, ansible

I have this simple Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: read file
  shell: cat "{{ '/home/myhome/confiles/file.txt' }}"
  register: config

- name: set regex for myvar 
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    myvar: |-
      {{
          config.stdout |
          regex_search('^number *= *.*', multiline=True) |
          regex_replace('.*= *(.*)$', '\1')
      }}

- name: debug myvar
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg:
      - myvar ---> {{ myvar }}
      - myvar ---> {{ myvar | type_debug }}
      - myvar ---> {{ myvar | int }}
      - myvar ---> {{ myvar |int | type_debug }}
```

that return this:

```yaml
TASK [query : debug myvar] **********
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": [
        "myvar ---> '5002'",
        "myvar ---> AnsibleUnsafeText",
        "myvar ---> 0",
        "myvar ---> int"
    ]
}
```

Expected result is:

```
"myvar ---> 5002"
```

Actual result is:

```
"myvar ---> 0"
```

Where is the problem? Why this behaviour?

Comment: Because `my_var` is `'5002'`, **quotes included**, you should probably fix your regex to not capture them. But without the content of _file.txt_, this is hard to help you on this.

Comment: So, probably: `regex_replace(".*= *'(.*)'$", '\1')`

Comment: Thanks. The line trapped from file is number='5002'.

Answer (score 0):

> *Because `my_var` is `'5002'`, **quotes included***

You can either adjust the regex and as already mentioned within the comments by β.εηοιτ.βε, or strip the quotes from your variable by using [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing/509295#509295) or a [Custom Filter Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins).

```yaml
{{ myvar[1:-1] | int }}
```

**Thanks to**

- [How to strip quotes from a variable in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57104817/6771046)
- [`filter_plugins/string_filters/string_filters.py`](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/string_filters/string_filters.py)